# "Object does not match target type" on basic Delegate example

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I'm playing around with Delegates, but I'm clearly not grasping something basic.

I've got the following:

```
class Test
{
    delegate bool Foo();

    public void Run()
    {
        Delegate foo = new Foo((delegate () { return true; }));
        bool result = (bool)foo.Method.Invoke(foo, null);
    }
}

Test test = new Test();
test.Run();
```

In the above example I encounter an exception: "Object does not match target type."

The following works alright, though:

```
class Test
{
    delegate bool Foo();

    public void Run()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo((delegate () { return true; }));
        bool result = foo.Invoke();
    }
}

Test test = new Test();
test.Run();
```

What's incorrect with my first implementation? Shouldn't I be invoking foo's method, as foo, with no parameters? This would seem equivalent to the latter code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're bypassing the entire reason you'd use the delegate in the first place. As a rule of thumb, *don't touch* `Method`.

The first argument in `MethodInfo.Invoke` is the `this` instance. This can be `null` or something else (e.g. a closure, or the actual object instance when the delegate represents an instance method), but it will *never* be the delegate instance - that doesn't make any sense.

In your case, it is indeed a closure instance. But you have no reference to the closure outside of the delegate - it's created behind the scene by the compiler. So the only proper way to do the invocation (using `MethodInfo`) would be `foo.Method.Invoke(foo.Target, null);`. Of course, this is entirely redundant - just use `foo();` like any sane human, and you'll be fine :)

The same way, stop using the old delegate syntax. There's little point in doing so. A simple

```
Func<bool> foo = () => true;
Console.WriteLine(foo());
```

will work fine. You can substitute your own delegate for `Func<bool>` if you really need to, but using custom delegates isn't very useful nowadays.

Comment: Thanks. This example code is extracted from a much larger code base which is why the code itself seems odd. Trying to understand why an exception is being thrown, but need to learn the mechanics of Delegates first.

Comment: @SeanAnderson Delegates are very simple - they're just the `Target`, plus the `Method` to be invoked. They're kind of like a single-method interface :) Unless you're doing reflection mumbo-jumbo, you don't care about either - just `Invoke` (or better, `(...)`), and you'll be fine. If somebody used `Delegate.Method.Invoke` instead of `Delegate.Invoke`, find them and ask why. Bring a baseball bat just in case.

Comment: The code is indeed doing reflection mumbo-jumbo. Reflection appears to be failing due to an out-of-date reference to a DLL which we're attempting to reflect on.. but not 100% confident on that which is why I am trying to boil the problem down a little bit first. I appreciate the detailed response though.

Comment: @SeanAnderson Well, just remember that using reflection for dangerous things (e.g. bypassing accessibility modifiers) requires Full Trust code security. The closure is usually either `private` or `internal` and the same goes for the anonymous method, so `Method.Invoke` will always fail outside of Full Trust. This may be a problem for many different reasons, e.g. inconsistent strong naming, GAC assemblies, assembly binding redirection... If you can get rid of it, do so. It will only bring you pain. If you need to do weird stuff with the functions and `Target`, create a new delegate instead.